# How to get the actual image from Picasa using Gdata

Tags: php, zend-framework, gdata

I am trying to output the actual URL to the high resolution image of a photoentry. A photo entry `Zend_Gdata_Photos_PhotoEntry` of the Gdata contains the data of photo stored in Picasa.

Currently, I found to methods to output URLs to images. The first is to output thumb images, they seem to be available in three different sizes. The second method is by `getContent()`. I expected that this method should get me the highest resolution URL. Instead, it contains one image url which is still smaller than the original in Picasa.

```
    $thumb = $entry->getMediaGroup()->getThumbnail();
    $content = $entry->getMediaGroup()->getContent();

    echo "<img src='" . $content[0]->getUrl() . "' />";      
    echo "<img src='" . $thumb[1]->getUrl() . "' />";
```

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935814/where-is-the-full-size-image-in-gdata-photos-query) it should be there unless it is protected by the owner, it seems.

Answer (score 3):

When building your query, add the **setImgMax** parameter as follows:

```
$query = $gp->newAlbumQuery();
$query->setUser($user);
$query->setAlbumId($album);
$query->setImgMax("d");
```

This way you will get the highest resolution available of the photo using the same code you posted.

Answer (score 1):

same [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935814/where-is-the-full-size-image-in-gdata-photos-query)

Outside of the php / zend aspect, it can help to understand the underlying abstract protocol for gdata/ picasa. I assume your provider for photos is picasa..

Regardless of the language that you are writing in, you can use generic tools like the [playground](https://code.google.com/oauthplayground/) in order to make tests exercising the protocol and to further understand all the aspects of the back and forth of the API you are trying to use.

The hi-res picture is in **media:group/media:content[@url]**

The other link has a long answer that shows how to do a GET against the api for a particular user/ album/ photo and how to find the tag containing the URL that you want.

Answer (score 1):

It might be simpler, change the size on url from **sXXX** to **s0**

[image]

to

[image]