# how to obtain actual urls for all images in a google picasa web album

Tags: picasa

I have a lot of images in a picasa web album, and I want to obtain the URL for all of the images in that album.

The sharing settings of that album are Visibility= Restricted, all with the link.

How do I get these URLs? I understand that I can open each image, then on the right hand side obtain the URL to that image-- however there are a lot of images in that album, so is there any other way to obtain this info?

I want the URL to the image in its original size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Firefox, a Greasemonkey script can be used that provides the actual link to some/all images in a Picasa album.

You need to navigate to the album's page in firefox, at the top the extension displays options- eg if you want urls for images of a specific size, or for some images only-- once these options are filled in you can easily obtain the link(s).

The greasemonkey script I used is at http://www.userscripts.org (Disclaimer- use such a script after ensuring that it is not malicious).

There are many such scripts (for obtaining links to images in a picasa album) at http://www.userscripts.org- just do a search and you will get a list of such scripts.

Answer (score 1):

you will need to use the picasa api with your 'userID' and the 'albumID'...

read picasa api to find out how to get those values... then

have a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592633/php-picasa-api-show-large-image)

that answer was for slightly different xslt expression applied to the 'fields=' part of the gdata request.

you want all the entries for the feed of the album... then within each entry you want the equivalent json of:

> "entry":   ["media$group":{
>       "media$content":[
>          {
>            "url"

So, when u figure out the oauth playground explained in the other answer, after you authenticate to "Picasa" service,  you can simply ask for this request string substituting for your (userID, albumID) :

```
/feed/api/user/rowntreerob/albumid/5682316071017984417?fields=entry%2Fmedia%3Agroup%2Fmedia%3Acontent%5B%40url%5D&alt=json
```

and use the Json parser to display your results , an excerpt of the first couple of pictures that u see below:

> { "version":"1.0", "encoding":"UTF-8", "feed":{
>   "xmlns":"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom",
>   "xmlns$gphoto":"http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007",
>   "xmlns$media":"http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/", "entry":[ {
>   "media$group":{ "media$content":[ {
>   "url":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-_FFMNGPU1TQ/TtukXyN4eCI/AAAAAAAACso/EzPmut2iKVQ/DSC01612.JPG",
>   "height":512, "width":341, "type":"image/jpeg", "medium":"image" } ] }
>   }, { "media$group":{ "media$content":[ {
>   "url":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-MhKoWh5MMxE/TtukZNnPvJI/AAAAAAAACkk/oz5fxA6qHx4/DSC01613.JPG",
>   "height":512, "width":341, "type":"image/jpeg", "medium":"image" } ] }
>   }, { "media$group":{ "media$content":[ {
>   "url":"https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-Bg9L7Cggfak/TtukZ0BtRiI/AAAAAAAACk0/2HiJtkEFUss/DSC01614.JPG",
>   "height":512, "width":341, "type":"image/jpeg", "medium":"image" } ] }
>   }, { "media$group":{ "media$content":[ {
>   "url":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-u-kqaskIfqc/TtukajDNYHI/AAAAAAAACk8/3jo9wS-zhbA/DSC01615.JPG",
>   "height":512, "width":341, "type":"image/jpeg", "medium":"image" } ] }
>   }, { "media$group":{ "media$content":[ {
>   "url":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-9OoGQKTh7CQ/Ttukh1ocOCI/AAAAAAAACgQ/fKy-0Ru7J4M/DSC01624.JPG",
>   "height":512, "width":341, "type":"image/jpeg", "medium":"image" } ] }
>   },

the pictures that u want are in the "url" attribute...