# Download full size/original image size from Google Picasa Web Album API

Tags: python, google-api, picasa

I am trying to download original full image size from Google +.

```
import gdata.photos.service
import gdata.media
import gdata.geo

gd_client = gdata.photos.service.PhotosService()
username = 
album_id = 
photos = gd_client.GetFeed(
    '/data/feed/api/user/%s/albumid/%s?kind=photo' % (
        username, album_id))
first_entry = photos.entry[0]
```

`first_entry.size` returns the proper size(original image). But `first_entry.content.src` returns URL which is not the original resolution and size.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11967955/how-to-obtain-actual-urls-for-all-images-in-a-google-picasa-web-album) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592633/php-picasa-api-show-large-image) gives something relevant. But they are not original image size you would get by clicking the 'Download Photo' on the picture preview.

But even `first_entry.media.content[0].url` as the links above suggests, it is not the original size of the image.

I followed this link: [Google Picasa Web Album API](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/1.0/developers_guide_protocol#ListPhotos)

Answer (score 4):

I implemented the following ...

```
def GetUserFeedHiRes(self, factory, kind='album', user='default', limit=None):
  uri = "/data/feed/api/user/%s?kind=%s&imgmax=d" % (user, kind)
  gd_client=factory.GetPhotoService()
  return gd_client.GetFeed(uri, limit=limit)
```

looking at the code in your question, you simply need to add the `&imgmax=d` component

Comment: You can also replace the /s-160-c/ by /s0/ and get the full image from the thumbnail URL.

Below the thumbnail URL

`https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-xGmQ/WoE0EE/AAAAE9Ss/JUD8KFWsLpqEFqEeH9W8wCHMYCg/s160-c/654941820388673`

And this is the full resolution image;

`https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-xGmQ/WoE0EE/AAAAE9Ss/JUD8KFWsLpqEFqEeH9W8wCHMYCg/s0/654941820388673`