# Finding the content element of a gdata entry

Tags: google-docs, gdata, gdata-api

The Google Documents List API (v3) references a "content element" several times.  In the content element there is a URI to export the file and the mime type of the file.

How can I find the content element and extract that information?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used google oauth playground to make a sample request - posted response on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/jQv1gFri)...

Following the 'title' element, you can see the 'content' element you requested with the URI containing a node=export.

```
"content":{
"type":"text/html",
"src":"https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id\u003d1mCHy6rcaqFoyZaJ-3qwRBZyirxnmew1m4CfEtOWAhjw\u0026v\u003d3"
},
```

once i authenticated to the playground , i used the following request for this example:

```
https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full?v=3&alt=json&max-results=1
```

Using playground and json prettyprint instructions in my answere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935814/where-is-the-full-size-image-in-gdata-photos-query)